# Can't read/get posted data on server side using fetch

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and i am trying to post data to my server.

On server side of MY_URL i just have basic code say   `return array("result" => $_POST);`

and below is my react native code.

```
fetch('MY_URL' , { method : "POST" ,  body : JSON.stringify({email: 'cjmling', password: 'aa' }) })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('Login Failed. Please try again');
        console.warn(error);
      });

  }
```

The problem is that at line where it say console.log(responseData). I am just getting response as `array("result" => array[0])` in the console log. So its confirm that MY_URL server is working and sending some response but it just don't seems to able to ready any post data.

Is there anything I am missing ?

Thanks

Comment: The fetch API looks correct, I would put some logs in your server to check params coming in. Are there any headers that have to be set, content-type, authorization, etc? Its impossible to figure out what's wrong without seeing the server implementation too.

Comment: In my situation, I use Django as a server, and I have to use `formdata` as a body or it would be wrong. So maybe you can try [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like for method POST my server implementation ( using Laravel , excluded token middleware in the route ) required header.

So I added this in fetch and it worked.

`headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`